# How to generate a random values between two hexcode in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to generate a list of hexcode between two values so I can use then to generate a range of colors.

What I am trying to achieve is this.

```
List.generate(36, (i) => generateRandomCode(0xFF0587D8, 0xFF0345B5))

generateRandomCode(min, max) {
    // implementation here
}
```

How do I generate this int in the function generateRandomCode?

Comment: Please note that the range is not just between numbers but hexcode, i.e 0xFF0587D8, 0xFF0345B5.

Comment: 0xFF0587D8: this value in flutter in considered to be of type int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generator:**

```
int generateRandomCode(int minValue, int maxValue) {
  return Random().nextInt((maxValue - minValue).abs() + 1) + min(minValue, maxValue);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
final list = List<int>.generate(36, (i) => generateRandomCode(0xFF0587D8, 0xFF0345B5));
print(list);
```

**Result:**

```
/flutter ( 6592): [4278422613, 4278508577, 4278489065, 4278486019, 4278499653, 4278480654, 4278464106, 4278474805, 4278462976, 4278549386, 4278537465, 4278418510, 4278496777, 4278405225, 4278411018, 4278412393, 4278461314, 4278538568, 4278549901, 4278510124, 4278492024, 4278530862, 4278517728, 4278425917, 4278442865, 4278497051, 4278430858, 4278497227, 4278462764, 4278412600, 4278448684, 4278422213, 4278464891, 4278473256, 4278543371, 4278476016]
```

You can still convert it to list of colors

```
final colorList = list.map((hex) => Color(hex)).toList();
print(colorList);
```

**Result:**

```
I/flutter ( 6592): [Color(0xff04c366), Color(0xff03d608), Color(0xff03a34a), Color(0xff048eac), Color(0xff03924a), Color(0xff03f0ba), Color(0xff052271), Color(0xff03ef8a), Color(0xff0582e0), Color(0xff0551ae), Color(0xff0402b3), Color(0xff0552be), Color(0xff050553), Color(0xff04c39f), Color(0xff053f88), Color(0xff04b6b8), Color(0xff05299f), Color(0xff03f1a7), Color(0xff03ca2f), Color(0xff04a864), Color(0xff04ee66), Color(0xff0358ce), Color(0xff03b741), Color(0xff046785), Color(0xff04ef11), Color(0xff04e618), Color(0xff03ff8a), Color(0xff03dc97), Color(0xff04353e), Color(0xff04cff6), Color(0xff03bfa4), Color(0xff049ca3), Color(0xff04bbac), Color(0xff03c5d3), Color(0xff05730b), Color(0xff036c8f)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use a List Generate Constructor**

```
new List<int>.generate(3, (int index) => index * index);
```

Link to the source : [Link generator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.17.1/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<int> createList(int min, int max) {
    return List.generate(max - min + 1, (i) => min + i);
  }
```

Result:

```
print(">>>>>>>>>> ${createList(10, 22).join(", ")}");
// >>>>>>>>>> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
```